# How to work while Selenium tests are working

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, lost-focus

When I write automated tests and run them (on my PC) I can not work until the tests are finished, because for example if I am coding the focus will jump out of visual studio to go to the web application under test viewed in web browser.

Is there a way to prevent Selenium driver from stealing focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only you can't prevent the `WebdDiver` from taking the focus, you shouldn't do it. The `WebdDiver` needs the focus on the browser in order to successfully interact with it. If you take the focus the `WebdDiver` won't be able to perform actions like `FindElement()`, `Click()` or any other operation and the tests will fail.

Comment: so we have to dedicate the machine for testing purposes only?

Comment: @YahyaHHussein We are using VMs to run our tests in parallel on dedicated machine. You can of course do it with a single VM or machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows 10 Virtual Desktops. Check here how to use it: https://www.howtogeek.com/197625/how-to-use-virtual-desktops-in-windows-10/